# How to apply padding on a Java String object

Tags: java

To ensure a fixed length between the last characters of two consequent strings
Example:

```
String1       String2q
     S1      String222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java language provides what you need in `String.format()`

```
String padded = String.format("%20-s", s);
```

This will print a string and then add spaces after it so it is always length 20.

You can either use this method or just put the format directly into your output code.

If you really want to always leave exactly 20 characters (which is not what your example shows) just define a string constant and use that:

```
private static final String PAD = "                ";
```

Comment: Why not just `String.format("%20s", s);` :)

Comment: `%20s` will left pad, he needs `%20-s`. I provided the slightly more general form just because I had the method handy. You are right simpler is probably better in this case though,